# Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-64353-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS, cause: Not Found

Tags: content-delivery, publishing

I am getting the error when publishing one particular page with a lot of nested components:

> Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-64353-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS, cause: Not Found

[image: Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-64353-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS, cause: Not Found]

There is nothing in the CM or the CD logs other than this error.  I suspect it's the size of the package and I've upped the `HttpsReceiver` `MaxSize` in cd_deployer_conf.xml and have upped the `httpRuntime` `maxRequestLength`, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Check IIS logs for clues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was missing the `requestLimits` element as in:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <!-- This is the value in **bytes** -->
        <!-- 524288000 bytes = 500MB -->
        <!-- The maximum for this is 4,294,967,295 (3.99GB) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/-->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
    </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Another useful answer to a very similar problem: [Tridion 2011 SP1 HTTPS Publishing throwing 'Post size exceeded allowed limits'](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/326/tridion-2011-sp1-https-publishing-throwing-post-size-exceeded-allowed-limits)