# Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-2421110-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS, cause: Internal Server Error

Tags: content-delivery

I am getting the following error while publishing any page in Tridion.

> Transport failed: Could not transport tcm_0-2421110-66560.Content.zip using HTTPS, cause: Internal Server Error

My pages are very small in size, so I don't expect this to be an issue with memory size. But when I restart the IIS server, publishing works again, however after some time it stops working and gives the same error.

Does anybody know what I can do to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Application log on the Deployer side? IIS usually logs the exception there. Other then that, output of the cd_core and cd_deployer logs would be helpful as well.

Comment: what version of SDL Tridion are you using?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked on this forum multiple times before, and the first step is to always look at the logs. Have you googled?

Comment: You mention that your pages are small, which is a hint that you might already have read http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1276/129 and that you don't think this is a duplicate. What do you mean by your pages being small? It's the size of the package that matters. How big are your packages?

Answer (score 2):

Your Internal Server Error is being thrown by the receiving end of your publishing transaction - your deployer web app - and I can't understand why it would fail *sometimes* but the reasons for it must be logged somewhere in one of the following locations:

- Windows Event Viewer - Application or System
- cd_core_log of the deployer
- IIS log

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and the below thread resolved my issue,

[Tridion 2011 SP1 HTTPS Publishing throwing 'Post size exceeded allowed limits'](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/326/tridion-2011-sp1-https-publishing-throwing-post-size-exceeded-allowed-limits)

Comment: Sry that is not it. I have the same issue as TS. The issue You describe is to be fixed with iis adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDL Tridion Content Manager DCOM+ application and navigate to the "Pooling and Recycling" tab and set the Memory Limit to 256 or 512 MB instead of zero and then see if you can still reproduce the issue.

Also, check with your System Admin if all the settings in IIS are all correct.

Further provide more information like - Which version of SDL Tridion you are using, Logs of Content Deployer while log level is set to DEBUG or TRACE, and we will be in better position to help you.

Comment: Configuring the app pool to recycle is a "band-aid", not a solution. It's much better to establish a root cause if possible. Of course, sometimes you need a band-aid.

Comment: Agreed and that's why I have requested for more details