# Trying to create a Component with the Core Service: Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: 2013, core-service, rtf

I'm trying to import some content into Tridion using the Core Service and have a problem with one of my Rich Text Fields when trying to save a new Component to Tridion.

I'm getting the following error:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2012:data. The
>   InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the
>   object of type Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IdentifiableObjectData.
>   Data at the root level is invalid. Line 5, position 11.'.

The inner exception doesn't really tell me more.

If I delete some of the HTML content it seems to work but I can't see any obvious issues with the deleted part of the content. There's not any special characters in there or broken tags. I'm still trying to narrow it down to a particular part.

If I paste my `ComponentData.Content` field into the Source of a Component using the same Schema in the CME the Component saves fine.

I can also paste the problem HTML into the source view of the RTF field and this saves fine.

I initially thought this was an encoding issue but it seems like something else is going on.

Has anyone seen anything similar before?

**Update**
By hardcoding the content of the field of my component I've discovered it seems to be to do with the length of the content..

This saves:

```
tridionArticle.Content =
                "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><p xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p></div>";
```

Whereas this does not:

```
tridionArticle.Content =
                    "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><p xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p><p xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p><p xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p><p xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p></div>";
```

Here's my code for saving a component:

```
  public void CreateItem(string folderId, TridionNewsArticleModel newsArticleModel)
    {
        using (var client = new CoreServiceClient(_binding))
        {
            var schemaFields =
                client.ReadSchemaFields(
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TridionNewsArticleSchema"], true, null);
            var componentData = (ComponentData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Component, folderId, new ReadOptions());

            componentData.Title = newsArticleModel.Title;
            componentData.Content = XmlSerializationHelper.Serialize(newsArticleModel);
            componentData.Schema.IdRef = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TridionNewsArticleSchema"];

            componentData.Content = HtmlTidy.DecodeHtmlEntities(componentData.Content, false);

            //TODO: is there a nicer way to do this?
            var metadataFields = Fields.ForMetadataOf(schemaFields, componentData);

            metadataFields["author"].Value = newsArticleModel.Author;
            metadataFields["pub_date"].Value = newsArticleModel.PubDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");

            //TODO: We're going to have to add a flag to the import for this
            metadataFields["audience_type"].Value = "Public";

            metadataFields["page_title"].Value = newsArticleModel.PageTitle;
            metadataFields["page_description"].Value = newsArticleModel.PageDescription;
            metadataFields["page_keywords"].Value = newsArticleModel.PageKeywords;

            metadataFields["google_page_priority"].Value = newsArticleModel.GooglePagePriority;
            metadataFields["google_update_frequency"].Value = newsArticleModel.GooglePagePriority;

            componentData.Metadata = metadataFields.ToString();
            try
            {
                client.Create(componentData, null);
                ConsoleWriter.Write(ConsoleColor.Green, "Successfully imported " + componentData.Title);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ConsoleWriter.Write(ConsoleColor.Yellow, ex.ToString());
                _log.Warn(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include a code sample

Comment: The content is client identifiable but added more detail / code above.

Comment: If it's related to the length of the content, perhaps the problem is with your binding(s)? Maybe you need to increase the max allowed length and such. I would expect a different error message, but perhaps it is masked by the one you are getting.

Comment: I've tried upping the limits on both client and server but it doesn't seem to have made any difference - any other ideas?

Comment: I've also tried the settings here on the off chance: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/326/tridion-2011-sp1-https-publishing-throwing-post-size-exceeded-allowed-limits/328#328

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately, this was an encoding issue.

I changed my serialization code from

```
 public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
 {
      XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
      using (MemoryStream wr = new MemoryStream())
        {
           XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
           ns.Add("", schemaNamespace);
           xs.Serialize(wr, obj, ns);
          return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(wr.GetBuffer());
       }
    }
}
```

to

```
    public static string Serialize<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, false); // no BOM in a .NET string
        settings.Indent = false;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and everything worked.

I am not sure why a shorter message worked and a longer did not.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this type of issue while creating a component with content in that. There the problem was with one of the field's content having `&` in between, so i replaced that with `&amp;` in code and my problem got solved. May be you can check for any special charector in your rich text field content.

Comment: My test data doesn't contain any ampersands. Thanks for your answer though.