# Information regarding using Core Service to create Components in SDL Web 8

Tags: core-service, web8

Recently I'm trying to use the Core Service in SDL Web 8 to create Components from XML files.

I found that the information on the SDL Documentation Center is not enough for me, and information from browser is a little messy.

Could anyone share some links from basic concepts to deep implementation?
Any share would be appreciated.
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you search this site for "[core service create component](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/search?q=core%20service%20create%20component)", you get more than 100 resuls and some of those are pretty much to what you are looking for. I'm seeing a complete code example of constructing a Component from XML in [Trying to create a Component with the Core Service: Data at the root level is invalid](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/trying-to-create-a-component-with-the-core-service-data-at-the-root-level-is-in), which translates into something like:

```cs
using (var client = new CoreServiceClient(endPoint))
{
    var componentData = (ComponentData)client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Component, folderUri, new ReadOptions()); 

    componentData.Title = "Your Title";
    componentData.Schema = new LinkToSchemaData { IdRef = schemaUri }
    componentData.Content = serializableXmlDocument;

    client.Create(componentData, new ReadOptions());
}
```

If you look through the documentation you also see a few examples regarding [creating items](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-5A946CBF-36D3-4D11-BE04-4901F9ED88E3), and specifically dealing with [Components](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3B59AFA5-5061-47C8-8C34-6773CE1B8EB6) and [fields](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3E10F24D-FC08-49B2-AA5F-704D6257985C).

All in all, I think all the information you are looking for is right there for you. If you encounter a specific issue with stringing all this example code together, that is something you could create a new question on.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at the **Core Service Recipies** section of the Tridion Cookbook: https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/CookbookDocumentation#core-service-recipies

Although it doesn't have a specific example for creating a Component, it does introduce some Core Service concepts nicely, using examples such as [Creating a new Publication](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/CreatingANewPublication) and [Changing the content and metadata of existing Components](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/ChangeContentOrMetadata).

Answer (score 1):

To create/migrate Tridion item using XmL is good option but its tricky when you have component link and media links etc.

- **Define your Schema** with simple fields to test.
- Title
- Description

**Create a class** in C# like following.

```
public class Book
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
        public string Synopsis{ get; set; }
   }
```

Fill this component with your required data and serialize it to disk as XML file.
Similarly you can Create XML for metadata of you component.

**Importing XML** (Code similar to @bart's)

```
 var componentData = (ComponentData)tridionClient.CoreServiceClient.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Component, folderId, readOptions);
        componentData.Title = componentDetails.Title;
        var schemaId = tridionClient.CoreServiceClient.Read(componentDetails.SchemaWebDavUrl, readOptions).Id;
        componentData.Schema.IdRef = schemaId;

        var schemaFields = tridionClient.CoreServiceClient.ReadSchemaFields(schemaId, true, readOptions);

        componentData.Content = UpdateNamespace(componentDetails.ComponentData, schemaFields.NamespaceUri).OuterXml; ;
        // this is custom method which add required namespace in the XML. assuming you are generating XML from another source and this namespace is missing

        if (componentDetails.MetaData != null)
        {
            componentData.Metadata = UpdateNamespace(componentDetails.MetaData, schemaFields.NamespaceUri).OuterXml);
        }
        tridionClient.CoreServiceClient.Create(componentData, readOptions);
```

- for any component link. you have to first create linked component and cache its tcm-id and put that tcm-in the parent component. this is very interesting part.
- Don't forget to put check of component/folder already exists
- Category keywords are just set of repeating nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program some time ago that imports RSS feed articles into components, you can see the code [here](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/kickstart-tridion-environment/tree/master/ImportContentFromRss/trunk).

Most of the CoreService logic is in [ContentItem.cs](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/kickstart-tridion-environment/blob/master/ImportContentFromRss/trunk/ImportContentFromRss/Content/ContentItem.cs) and in the main [Program.cs](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/kickstart-tridion-environment/blob/master/ImportContentFromRss/trunk/ImportContentFromRss/Program.cs). It may be a bit more complex than what you need to get started , but I always see this as a good example of mapping content to a proper class structure, and then using class inheritance/OO logic to deal with the CRUD operations via CoreService.