# How to increase size of incoming request of HTTP upload on hosted on Linux box

Tags: httpupload, linux

We have hosted our HTTP Upload on a Linux box. While publishing binary having size more then 1.5 MB it throws error.I am suspecting that this is a Size limit issue with Deployer and HTTP upload.

Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed. Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-21361-66560

I have changed the value in Deployer config from  10000000 to 104857600

HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="104857600" Location="D:\tridion\incoming" InProcessDeploy="true"/>

Where do i need to change this in Linux box?

Same issue has been see in windows at below link.

[Tridion 2011 SP1 HTTPS Publishing throwing 'Post size exceeded allowed limits'](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/326/tridion-2011-sp1-https-publishing-throwing-post-size-exceeded-allowed-limits)

Please suggest ?

Comment: This is likely to be an Application Server limitation (like in Windows it's an IIS configuration). It would help if you share which App Server you're using.

Comment: We are using WebSphere 8.5 to host http upload.

Answer (score 2):

It entirely depends which web server you are using. For example: if you are using Tomcat, then you may want to follow the below link:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/ajp.html

Here refer the `maxPostSize` property which you should be considering.

Share the specific Web Server you are using, and the community will be in better shape to help you out :)

Answer (score 2):

WebSphere:
you can look at following to increase PostSizeLimit key, if value is less than your required.

1. https://serverfault.com/questions/311610/how-to-increase-the-size-of-http-post-request-in-websphere
2. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21460889