# Increase Zip size for Transport

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, transport

We are trying to publish a component with a video and when the Zip is generated in the transport step we are getting an error of disk space:

```
2015-12-02 08:01:08,295 ERROR ZipWorker - Unable to zip the transport package source
java.io.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at com.tridion.util.ZipUtils.addFile(ZipUtils.java:172) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.util.ZipUtils.addFolder(ZipUtils.java:155) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.util.ZipUtils.addFolder(ZipUtils.java:153) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.util.ZipUtils.addFolder(ZipUtils.java:153) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.util.ZipUtils.addFolder(ZipUtils.java:153) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.util.ZipUtils.createArchive(ZipUtils.java:82) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.util.ZipUtils.createArchive(ZipUtils.java:62) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.ZipWorker.doWork(ZipWorker.java:57) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.StepPrepare.execute(StepPrepare.java:47) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.transport(TransactionProcessor.java:63) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.TransactionManager.transport(TransactionManager.java:43) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.TransportService.handleTransaction(TransportService.java:260) [cd_transport.jar:na]
```

The video has a size of 70MB and we checked that we have enough disk space (11GB).

Then, we think that there is a limit for the size of the Zip files. I think I remember there is a config parameter to set the size of the zip, but I cannot find in the SDL documentation.

Comment: where did you check for Space, CM or CD?

Comment: For future reference, here is the answer relating to the size of transport package (zip file) that the deployer (when using HTTP(S)) can accept: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/328/71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I make a wrong analysis.

If I put in the publication queue this components alone, it works fine. It's a combination with other components in other publications with the same video.

Then I suppose that the combination of all the processes is consuming 11Gb. We changed the path to another disk with 40Gb and now works fine.

Comment: Indeed note that when you publish a Component, you will be publishing all the Pages that this Component is referenced on (including the Pages that contain a Component that links to this Component). So depending on your  usage, it could be a very large list of items that you are publishing, resulting in a large transport paackage.

Answer (score 1):

A `Java.io.IOException; there is not enough space on the disk`
is simply thrown, when you try copying something to a destination drive, and the drive does not have enough space available.

`Java.io.IOException` exceptions are produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations. In this case an interupted IO operation and the reason is there is not enough space on the disk, it really is as the message tells you.

Now the challenge you have is to figure out which drive, when you say you have 11GB available, where is that? There are a few things you can check:

1. where is this error being logged (which log; CM eventlog, cd_transport log or on de CD side in one of its logs?)
2. where are the Publisher temp files stored (check the Publisher settings in the SDL Tridion Content Manager MMC snap-in, defaults to `C:\Temp`)
3. where are the Transport service temp files stored (check the `cd_transport_conf.xml` and look for the `WorkFolder` location, defaults to `./transactions` which is something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\transactions`, depending on where you installed SDL Tridion)